# Design suggestions required on LOG or Transaction History

Tags: database-design, application-design

I am developing a web application where users belonging to different groups will be filling out the form and submitting the same. Scenario is, User A, B and C belonging to Group G. User A logs into the app, fills up the form (say age=30), submits the same and logged out. Now, User B logs into the app, opens up the same form (say age=35), edits the form and saves it. Now, User C does the same thing (say age=40). When another user opens up the form, it will show the age as 40 ( as it is the latest record).

Question is, if an admin logs into the app, he/she should be able to see all the history of the transactions or logs. Please suggest me some design approach where all the changes are logged into the database. Is there any framework like spring or hibernate or any help to achieve this? Any inputs on database design will also help me.

I am using Struts and plain JDBC with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This can be approached in multiple ways.

1. Log4j Logging. Agree a pattern and log the updates in the log file. You have tools like sumologic or splunk or Kibana which can index the log files. However these solutions cannot hold the logging for ever. Typically you can design them to hold for say 3months data. You can query on key words and you will get results in milli seconds!

   2. If you are using hibernate, then you have something called as envers. Which record the latest db row into audit table before modifying it. But the limitation is you need to be on hibernate
   3. Use db triggers. On update trigger (atleast mysql) gives u the changed columns and you may record them. The only problem is capturing the user who had done the operation --which can be sent to mysql connection as 'temp variable'. However DBAs cry when u tell about triggers (why? i ddont know!)